# Contain with alias not working in cakephp 5.x

Tags: php, cakephp

I've set an alias 'Vehicle' for the 'vehicle' table. However, when retrieving the results, the object name is 'vehicle' (the table name) instead of the expected alias 'Vehicle'.

The output is

[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nTuFI.png)

Below is the code of my model class **Vehicle**

```
namespace App\Model\Table;

use Cake\ORM\Table;

class VehicleTable extends Table
{
    public function initialize(array $config): void
    {
        parent::initialize($config);
        $this->setTable( 'vehicle' );
         $this->setAlias('Vehicle');
        $this->addBehavior('Timestamp');

      
   }

    }
```

In this class I am joining vehicle table and I am calling this getDetails function inside the controller

```
namespace App\Model\Table;

use App\Lib\Utility;

use Cake\Collection\Collection;
use Cake\ORM\Table;

class TripTable extends Table {
    public function initialize( array $config ): void {
        parent::initialize( $config );
        $this->setTable( 'trip' );
        $this->addBehavior( 'Timestamp' );
        
         $this->belongsTo('Vehicle', [
            'foreignKey' => 'vehicle_id',
        ] );
}



    public function getDetails($driver_id,$starting_point)
    {

        $query = $this->find()
                      ->where( [ 'Trip.user_id' => $driver_id ] )
                      ->where( [ 'Trip.completed' => 0 ] )
                      ->contain( [
                        
                          'Vehicle'
                          
                        
                      ] )
                      ->limit( 10 )
                      ->offset( $starting_point * 10 )
                      ->orderby( [ 'Trip.id' => 'DESC' ] );

        $result = $query->toArray();
        return $result;

    }


}
```

Comment: When you retrieve the results, the property name for the vehicle object isn't named based on the table name or the alias, but the snake-cased singularized name of the association. If you changed your association to `$this->belongsTo('BlahBlahBlah'` (with other edits to set which table class to use for that association, then your "vehicle" record would be in `$trip->blah_blah_blah`.

Comment: @GregSchmidt I don't understand your answer. So you mean the results can't be retrieved with Alias

Comment: I mean that the alias doesn't affect the naming of the property that the results are returned in. If you want to change that, use `$this->belongsTo(...)->setProperty(...)`